# SwiftUI WKWebView below NavigationView not accepting displayMode

Tags: ios, swiftui, wkwebview

I created a tabview where the first tab contains a WKWebView

```
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    let urlString : String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: urlString)!))
    }
}
```

The webview is used as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            NavigationView {
                WebView(urlString: "...")
                .navigationBarTitle("Intérieur", displayMode: .large)
            }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName:"...")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("brownGrey"))
                    Text("...")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("brownGrey"))
                }
            }.tag(0)
```

But no matter what I try, I can't force the `NavigationView` to stay in `displayMode: .large`

The navigation bar goes to small mode until I scroll the webview's contents, then it goes to large.

If I replace in the above code the webview with a simple `Text("...")` it works as intended. Inserting the `Text("...")` above the webview also works, but I would like to do it without introducing an artificial spacer.

This is what happens when starting the app:

The title shows normally, while the webview's contents are loading:
[image: pre webview load]

Once the contents are loaded the NavigationView reduces its size:
[image]

If I pull down on the webview and let go the NavigationView shows the way I want it to show:
[image]

Seems to me that there is some magic going on where the system detects that it's a `WKWebview` below the navigation bar and therefore adapts its behaviour.

Any solution to this?

Comment: So basically you're just trying to force large title?

Comment: Yes. At least before the user starts scrolling the web page

Comment: See my answer, Joris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `WebView` in a `VStack` together with `ZStack` (with explicit frame) and with Color that has solid color works.

```
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection){
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Color(.gray)
                }.frame(width: 1, height: 1, alignment: .center)
                WebView(urlString: "https://prettyitgirl.blogspot.com/")
            }.navigationBarTitle("PrettyItGirl.com", displayMode: .large)
        }
...
```

Not providing explicit frame will give you an auto sized `ZStack`.

[image]